# execute a batch script from node in seperate comamnd line

Tags: node.js, exec

call a batch file from node script and run that batch file in separate cmd with out executing the running script cmd

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('C:\\Users\\priyanka.sukumaran\\Desktop\\vm-server\\appiumStart.bat', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

but while running the above script the batch file will not execute in seperate cmd it executed in the same cmd of the script i run.
**How can i excute the batch file in seperate command line????????**

Comment: You have to escape all backslashes in the path, currently you only have first one. You could use slash as path separator too, it will work on windows and wouldn't require escaping.

Comment: means i need to use path as `D:\\test_automation\\servers\\vms-server\\appiumStart.bat` is it??

Comment: but nothing will happend

Comment: it only prints "inside" not exeute that bat file

Comment: what does the err objet contain?